# Fixing Fibonacci sequence script (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to write a script that will create numbers in Fibonacci order, I don't understand why this is not working.

```
var output = [];
var n = output.length;
var nextNum = output[n-1] + output[n-2];

function fibo (numQuantity) {
for (var i=1; i<numQuantity ; i++)
{
  if (n>1){ 
  output.push(nextNum);
  console.log(output);
}
else if (n<2)
  {output.push(1);
  console.log(output);}
}
}
```

Comment: your n value never changes also your nextNum value never changes?

Comment: Youre not changing n anywhere. It remains 0 as assigned at var n = output.length;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code your n never changes as you only assigned it on start.

```js
    var output = [];


    function fibo (numQuantity) {
    for (var i=1; i<numQuantity ; i++)
    {
      var n = output.length;
      var nextNum = output[n-1] + output[n-2];
      if (n>1){ 
        output.push(nextNum);
        console.log(output);
      }
      else if (n<2)
      {
        output.push(1);
        console.log(output);
      }
    }
    }

    fibo(10)
```

In Javascript numbers are passed by value not reference so they are not the same object in memory. So when the array length changes your n value stays at 0 because they are not the same object.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fibo(numQuantity) {
  let output = [0, 1];
  
  if(numQuantity < 2) {
    return output.slice(0, numQuantity);
  }
  
  for(let i = 2; i < numQuantity ; i++) {
    const n = output.length
    output.push(output[n - 1] + output[n - 2])
  }
  
  return output;
}

console.log(fibo(1))
console.log(fibo(2))
console.log(fibo(3))
console.log(fibo(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/37a4burz/

You need to add `n++` to end of your code and change end condition.

Here is full code:

```
var output = [];
var n = output.length;
var nextNum = output[n-1] + output[n-2];

function fibo (numQuantity) {
    for (var i=1; i<= numQuantity ; i++)
    {
        if (n==0) {
            output.push(0);
            console.log(output);
        }
        else if (n==1) { 
            output.push(1);
            console.log(output);
        }
        else if (n>1) {
            output.push(output[n-1] + output[n-2]);
            console.log(output);
        }

        n++;
    }
}

fibo(7);
```